# Pycharm: Why does 'go-to declaration' jumps to file inside site-packages instead of local file?

Tags: pycharm

As the title suggests:
'go-to declaration' jumps to file inside site-packages instead of local file.

Answer (score 0):

'Mark directory' (the right one) as 'source root' fixes the issue.